# creating new fragments with class and id behaves strangely in IE8

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of code which works in Firefox

```
link = $('<a>link</a>');
var name = $("<h3 class='name section'>").append(link);
$('#container').append(name);
```

However this doesn't work in IE8. It seems that name doesn't get created at all. I tried adding `console.log('class of name'+name.attr('class'));` and inside the Developer Toolbar, the result is undefined.

Hence I look around for another option, and this works:

```
var name = $('<h3>');
name.addClass('name');
name.addClass('section');
name = name.append(link);
```

It does exactly the same thing. I was wondering if IE8 has a thing against using HTML to define DOM fragments, so I tried this:

```
var name = $("<div class='name section'>").append(link);
```

And this works in IE8.

What esoteric law of jQuery/IE8 did I break? Is it preferable to use addClass or setting the attribute of new DOM fragments over literal HTML?

Comment: What happens if you switch your quotes around, so that the double-quotes are used on the attributes? e.g. `var name = $('<h3 class="name section">')`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the HTML code correct by adding an ending tag to the `h3` tag, it works:

```
link = $('<a>link</a>');
var name = $("<h3 class='name section'></h3>").append(link);
$('#container').append(name);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think the closing tag is important.